# error: failed to push some refs to new repository

Tags: git, github

I am having some difficulty understanding what the errors are trying to tell me.  I created a new repository on Githhub and then remotely added the link given.  As a total noob, any advice would be appreciated!

```
Neelesh@Neelesh-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/RCB_Classwork/Introduction_work (develop)
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/ntekal/Professional.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ntekal/Professional.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are operating from the 'develop' branch instead of your master, which isn't allowing you to 'push origin master'. Being you are operating within a branch, you can merge it to your master in github, or possibly even 'cd ..' to your master repo and then try to ''git push origin master'' again. Also a noob, so hope this helps!